# Cannot set the org-agenda to start my week on monday

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In `org-agenda` I am trying to change the start of my week to monday by adding this to my `.emacs` file:

`(setq org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)`

Without success. The week (in the mini calendar, when I try to schedule a task) always starts with sunday).

Also `M-x customize-variable [return] org-agenda-start-on-weekday` and setting it to `1` didn't help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(why are you asking this on both StackExchange and Reddit?)

That's not the org-agenda, that's the calendar. Try

```
(setq calendar-week-start-day 1)
```

(btw, org-agenda-start-on-weekday is '1' by default)

Comment: I wasn't sure which platform is more responsive. Will stick to one from now on. - Thank you.

Comment: They both come with zero guarantee of any response at all. StackExchange is better for questions, in my opinion, reddit is better for discussions.

Answer (score 2):

If that doesn't help, you can use the below to set the start day to today for org-agenda.

`(setq org-agenda-start-day (org-today))`

Comment: Excellent! Just the other day I wondered how I could do that.